# access asp.net webcalendar in event-handler from dropdownlist event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DayRenderEventHandler for a webcalendar. I want that same event to fire off each time a name from a dropdownlist is selected and the only thing that needs to change in the DayRenderEvent is a string in a database query (the selected name).

How do I do that? Every time a name is selected, I want the calendar to show the database entries for the selected person.

Do I need to write the whole code again for the dropdown list event? And if so, how do I access the webcalendar?

Or can I somehow call the DayRenderEvent and pass the selected name as a parameter?

My DayRenderEvent method looks like this:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRenderEventHandler(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

               //Database stuff

                if (maxCode != null && maxCode2 != null)
                {
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    ds = new DataSet();
                    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    list1 = new DropDownList();
                    list1.DataSource = ds;
                    list1.DataTextField = "A_TYPE";
                    list1.DataValueField = "A_TYPE";
                    list1.DataBind();

                    da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                    ds2 = new DataSet();
                    da2.FillSchema(ds2, SchemaType.Source);
                    da2.Fill(ds2);

                    list2 = new DropDownList();
                    list2.DataSource = ds2;
                    list2.DataTextField = "A_Type";
                    list2.DataValueField = "A_Type";
                    list2.DataBind();

                    DayOfWeek comptag = e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek;
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string thisday = e.Day.Date.ToString();
                        string dayfromdb = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
                        list.Add(dayfromdb);

                        if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && dayfromdb == thisday)
                        {
                            e.Cell.Controls.Add(list2);
                        }
                        else if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && list.Contains(thisday) == false)
                        {
                            e.Cell.Controls.Add(list1);
                        }
                    } // for
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cell.Text = "MaxCode or MaxCode2 == null";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exptn)
            {
                string exp = exptn.StackTrace;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        } // DayRenderEventHandler
```

Now if I use the same code in the OnSelectedIndexChanged-Event for the dropdown list, it doesn't recognize the e.Cell and e.Day.Date and so on (I guess because, to my understanding, the event source in the DayRenderEvent is the Calendar1 and in the OnSelectedIndexChanged it's the dropdownlist).

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

+++++ EDIT ++++++++++

method for db-connection

```
private SqlConnection DBConnect()
{
    con = new SqlConnection();
    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

method for dataset

```
 private DataSet createDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

method for iterating over calendar-days

```
private void CalendarIterate(DataSet ds2, DayOfWeek comptag, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string thisday = e.Day.Date.ToString();
                string dayfromdb = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
                liste.Add(dayfromdb);

                if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && dayfromdb == thisday)
                {
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(list2);
                }
                else if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && liste.Contains(thisday) == false)
                {
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(list1);
                }
            }
        }
```

These methods are now called in the DayRender-Method (which still creates a db-connection for each day, I still need to look at that).

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRenderEventHandler(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con = DBConnect();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("", con);
                cmd2 = new SqlCommand("", con);
                maxCode = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                maxCode2 = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

                if (maxCode != null && maxCode2 != null)
                {
                    list1 = new DropDownList();
                    list1.DataSource = createDataSet(cmd);
                    list1.DataTextField = "A_TYP";
                    list1.DataValueField = "A_TYP";
                    list1.DataBind();

                    list2= new DropDownList();
                    list2.DataSource = createDataSet(cmd2);
                    list2.DataTextField = "A_Typ";
                    list2.DataValueField = "A_Typ";
                    list2.DataBind();

                    DayOfWeek comptag = e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek;
                    CalendarIterate(createDataSet(cmd2), comptag, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cell.Text = "MaxCode or MaxCode2 == null";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exptn)
            {
                string exp = exptn.StackTrace;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic case for refactoring (and adhering to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle). The easiest thing I would suggest is to identify the common code that will be shared between the two events and extract that using the refactor - extract method functionality in Visual Studio.

Another key principle you're breaking is the 'S' in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29). Look at the responsibilitys your method has been tasked with. It's performing a database query, iterating over the results and then manipulating the calendar control. This really needs to be broken down into seperate methods. This will make testing and bug fixing a whole lot easier (and you'll prevent dupliate code). Although the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is documented to apply to classes I try my best to apply it to my methods as well.

I know I haven't maybe provided the answer you would hope for (i.e. a full code sample) but if you break it down and stick to DRY you'll end up with much cleaner code.

Comment: Yeah, I know, the code is far from being good (I'm just too new to programming). I'll definitely have to optimize the code at some point but right now I'm just looking for a working solution. Once I have that, I'll look at making the code better. Thanx though for the links!

Comment: But again: assume I put the iteration into a different method: Then I would have to pass the DayOfWeek comptag as a prameter, the DataSet as a parameter and a DayRenderEvent as a parameter. I could then only use that Iteration-Method for the DayRenderEvent... and then I'm stuck with the same problem, that I cannot access it from within the SelectedIndexChanged event method...

Comment: I think you may need to think a bit more about your design, the DayRender event is called once for every day in the calendar so you'll end up making that many database calls. This is not good. You need to minimise the database calls, ideally only calling them once. I would suggest you refactor you DB calls out of this method, store the results somewhere and then use those in this method. One option (which may or may not work) would be to set the autopostback property of the dropdown to true, when the page reloads the calendar will re-render executing your logic.

Comment: I've already set the autopostback to true and there is a connection when I hit the button. I'm only struggling with how to render the calendar. My problem right now is that I dont know how to access the cells of the calendar from outside the DayRenderEvent. Say, for instance, I want to dynamically add a dropdownlist to the calendar once the SelectedIndexChanged-method fires off. That must be possible somehow, mustnt it?

Comment: I don't think you can access the cells outside of the DayRender event but that shouldn't matter. When the SelectedIndexChanged of the dropdown fires the DayRender event will be called (as part of the postback). e.g. Adding if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1){  e.Cell.Controls.Add(new DropDownList());} will add a new dropdown list control to each day if the second item in the dropdown list is selected. I'm not sure if that helps?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, I was out of office a couple of days. I updated my code according to your suggestions (hope I didnt make it worse :D). Where would I now put the "if(DropdownList1.SelectedIndex...) bit that you suggested in your last comment?

Comment: Update: So to make it clear once again. What I basically need to do is execute the same code as in the DayRenderEvent but with the name that was selected from the dropdownlist, which I will then use in the db query.

Comment: *I think* you're almost there, if I understand your code correctly you're already creating some dropdown lists in the DayRenderEvent but you're not doing anything with them, they need to be added to the e.Cell.Controls collection. Just add the 'If' check inside this method (DayRenderEvent), I think that'll work. I don't think you need to write any logic with the selectedIndexChanged event (of the drop down). Looks like your code is a little bit tidier now!

Comment: What I'm doing in the DayRenderEvent is this: I get the connection, write SQL-statements, get the DataSet and then create 2 dropdown lists for displaying the data from the db and pass the lists to CalendarIterat. If for the day being rendered there's an entry, I display that entry in the dropdown-list. That works. But what I want to do is: if I choose a name from another dropdownlist (not created in DayRenderEvent), I need that same thing to happen, but for a different user. I basically need to make the same sql statements for a different user and display THAT user's data in the calendar.

Comment: ... I guess ill have to outsource the SqlCommands to be able to use the name selected in the other dropdownlist. But I need to fire off the dayRenderEvent whenever I choose a name from that list. Sorry if I misunderstood your comment and you already gave the correct answert, but it looks like your checking the lists created in the DayRenderEvent. or am I just blind?